# Terminal Services - RDP Printing

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server

We are looking for a terminal server printing application to help fix our remote printing issue.

We looked at TSPrint from TerminalWorks but found it had a few bugs and so was not a complete solution.

Does anyone have any experience with any other app's which work in a similar way. ie copy the file locally and the print it to improve speed as well as fix printing issue?

Comment: Printing issue? And how does it handle it, it's actually copying files over to the local workstation and handling the printing there?

Comment: What are you current issues. And what operating system are you using?

Comment: We are using Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-bit and Windows Xp and 7 clients. We do use EasyPrint but find it has issues such as not working with some printers, slowness etc - Yes TerminalWorks does copy the files from its server app to the client app and print them on the client. It very fast but we have different printing issues with their app such as the page being printed is not copy out the correct size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Server 2008 printing has been enhanced by the addition of the Terminal Services Easy Print printer driver and a Group Policy setting that enables you to redirect only the default client printer.

The Terminal Services Easy Print driver is a feature in Windows Server 2008 that enables users to reliably print from a Terminal Services RemoteApp™ program or from a terminal server desktop session to the correct printer on their client computer. It also enables users to have a much more consistent printing experience between local and remote sessions.

You can also take a look at [ThinPrint](http://www.thinprint.com/). Thinprint offers a very complete solution useable in almost every environment concerning printer problems and issues. All components like one printer driver, compression, bandwidth control are available and a lots of settings are possible like Dedicated Printer Server, Dedicated Printer Server over RDP/ICA, Client Gateways, Thinprint Hardware.

Comment: Yes we are using Easy Print but find it has lots of issues: such as not working with some printers, slow etc - I assume ThinPrint is expensive?

Comment: I would advise you to get a quote,and then you will know If Thinprint is expensive. Something being expensive if very subjective, what I find cheap, you can find it expensive, and the other way around ;).